# drf-spectacular Can't find inspector class

Tags: django

I am trying to set up drf-spectacular to generate an AutoSchema for my djangorestframework API.

I have set it up as explained in the Readme, e.g., in installed apps, version = "~=0.11.1", and in the rest framework settings as below:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
...,
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': ('drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',),
}
```

My djangorestframework is version 3.12.
I am getting an error when I run the following command:
`./manage.py spectacular --file schema.yml`

Here's an example view of mine:

```
class LinkListView(ListView):

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    template_name = "core/linklist.html"
    context_object_name = "link_list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Org.objects.all()
```

After reading a bunch on schemas, I'm thinking that I have some other library that is conflicting with this or that some previous other swagger alternatives are conflicting. Does this make sense based on the error? Is there something I'm missing to try?

Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 19, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/drf_spectacular/management/commands/spectacular.py", line 50, in handle
    schema = generator.get_schema(request=None, public=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/drf_spectacular/generators.py", line 188, in get_schema
    paths=self.parse(request, public),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/drf_spectacular/generators.py", line 130, in parse
    self._initialise_endpoints()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/drf_spectacular/generators.py", line 113, in _initialise_endpoints
    self.endpoints = self.inspector.get_api_endpoints()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/drf_spectacular/generators.py", line 22, in get_api_endpoints
    api_endpoints = self._get_api_endpoints(patterns, prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/drf_spectacular/generators.py", line 55, in _get_api_endpoints
    nested_endpoints = self._get_api_endpoints(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/drf_spectacular/generators.py", line 49, in _get_api_endpoints
    if self.should_include_endpoint(path, callback):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/schemas/generators.py", line 120, in should_include_endpoint
    if callback.cls.schema is None:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/schemas/inspectors.py", line 120, in __get__
    assert issubclass(inspector_class, ViewInspector), (
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

My libraries:

```
[packages]
django = "~=3.1"
psycopg2 = "*"
djangorestframework = "~=3.12"
django-extensions = "*"
python-dotenv = "~=0.9"
django-cors-headers = "*"
django-filter = "*"
freezegun = "*"
pip = "*"
pytz = "*"
packaging = "*"
python-jose = "~=3.0"
cryptography = "~=2.0.3"
requests = "*"
twine = "*"
pyjwt = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
whitenoise = "*"
dj-database-url = "*"
boto = "*"
drf-spectacular = "~=0.11.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

this is most likely just a minor setup problem. You defined `DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS` as a tuple of a string and not **just a string**. Django probably resolved this to a list/tuple with one class as item. The error message makes sense then, as a tuple is not a class. i hope that resolves your issue. This is how it should be:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # YOUR SETTINGS
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}
```